# Shell script isn't logged in matrix project

Tags: jenkins

I have a simple matrix project created with Jenkins.

I am trying to execute a simple shell script. Before that I run svn checkout to get the sources. I tried a lot of ways to execute the shell script, but all doesn't work.
That means I can't see the output of the shell script.

Following lines I had tried to execute:

```
_make.sh
./_make.sh
bash -ex _make.sh

#!/bin/sh
./_make.sh
```

I had manually chmod'ed the file (*_make.sh*) on 755, but it makes no difference.

Thanks for any advices.

EDIT:
I got always following output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ABC/workspace
Triggering all
all completed with result FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

*_make.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "A" > test

g++ -c src/*.cc src/*.h -pthread -D_REENTRANT  -I"gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4" -I"gtkmm/lib/gtkmm-2.4/include" -I"gtkmm/include/giomm-2.4" -I"gtkmm/lib/giomm-2.4/include" -I"gtkmm/include/pangomm-1.4" -I"gtkmm/lib/pangomm-1.4/include" -I"gtkmm/include/gtk-2.0" -I"gtkmm/include/gtk-unix-print-2.0" -I"gtkmm/include/atkmm-1.6" -I"gtkmm/include/gdkmm-2.4" -I"gtkmm/lib/gdkmm-2.4/include" -I"gtkmm/include/glibmm-2.4" -I"gtkmm/lib/glibmm-2.4/include" -I"gtkmm/include/glib-2.0" -I"gtkmm/lib/glib-2.0/include" -I"gtkmm/include/sigc++-2.0" -I"gtkmm/lib/sigc++-2.0/include" -I"gtkmm/include/cairomm-1.0" -I"gtkmm/lib/cairomm-1.0/include" -I"gtkmm/include/pango-1.0" -I"gtkmm/include/cairo" -I"gtkmm/include/pixman-1" -I"gtkmm/include/freetype2" -I"gtkmm/include/directfb" -I"gtkmm/include/libpng12" -I"gtkmm/lib/gtk-2.0/include" -I"gtkmm/include/atk-1.0" -I"gtkmm/include/gio-unix-2.0" -I"gtkmm/include/fontconfig" -I"gtkmm/include" -D FREEGLUT_STATIC -I"freeglut/include/GL" -I"freeglut/include" -I"freeglut/include" -I"DevIL/include" -I"mysql/include" -I"lib3ds" -mconsole

g++ *.o -o test.exe -pthread -L"gtkmm/lib"-lgtkmm-2.4 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-2.4 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -L"freeglut/lib" -L"DevIL/lib" -L"lib3ds/lib3ds/.libs" -L"gtkglextmm/gtkglext/gtkmm/gl/.libs" -L"gtkglextmm/gdkglext/gdkmm/gl/.libs" -L"mysql/lib/opt" -l3ds -lgtkglextmm-win32-1.2-0 -lgdkglextmm-win32-1.2-0 -lmysql -lfreeglut -lDevIL -lilut -lfreeglut_static -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lws2_32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mconsole
```

Comment: 1) What is the console output?
2) Have you manually checked that the file is actually in the workspace - matrix builds have a complex directory structure. Go to one of the child builds by clicking on its ball in the matrix, then click on 'workspace' there, do you see your file?

Comment: Output see above and yes the file is in the workspace at the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can judge from your output it is from the parent job - not from a matrix sub-job (otherwise it would say 'Started by upstream project...').

You need to get to the child console output - and then I am sure it will become clear why it fails. You get to the child project by clicking on its ball within the parent project and then look for 'Console Output' link.

Or you you can try to get to it manually - it will be somewhere in `[jenkins_root]/jobs/[parent_job_name]/configurations/**/builds/[build_id]/log` (where `**` means any multiple level down the directory tree).

Note that as @Sagar suggests your files have to be checked out into the child project workspace, not the parent.

Comment: Thanks so far, that was the problem. Now I found the log files, which contains the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Question: Is your script also checked out from Subversion?

=====

Make sure _make.sh is actually in your workspace. The matrix job workspace is at:

```
http://yourserver.com/jenkins/jobs/<JOBNAME>/label=<SLAVEorLABEL-NAME>/ws/
```

Assuming that it is,

In your "Execute Shell", try the following:

```
source ./_make.sh
```

or

```
source ./_make.sh 2>&1
```

In your _make.sh, make sure you have either **#!/bin/bash** or **#!/bin/sh** depending on which you need.

Another thing you can try to see if the script is working at all, is to add the following line to the script and run it:

```
echo "A" > test
```

If the file test exists in the workspace after the script has run and it contains "A", your script is executing.

Finally, there is one other reason why your script won't execute, although this should normally give you an error.

If you created your script in Windows, you may the wrong line endings. Try:

```
dos2unix _make.sh
```

This will convert the line endings to unix style. I have faced this issue, but for me it displayed an error.

Comment: To your question, yes it is from SVN, but it makes no difference. I have done a checkout and after that disabled SVN. Nothing of your mentioned thinks helped me. The test file is created, but there is no console output in any cases. I have tested with a simple echo in the script, no success.